# “The show was one of the dullest we have ever seen” – tense consistency

Tags: tenses, past-tense, sequence-of-tenses

This sentence is from a English textbook written by an English native speaker:

> The show was one of the dullest we have ever seen

Because it used *was,* the sentence is talking about things in the past. Even if the show was still one of the dullest till now, the viewpoint is in the past, so shouldn’t we use *had* as follows?

> The show was one of the dullest we **had** ever seen.

Did I misunderstood the grammar rule on tense consistency?

Comment: I think that you're using past tense progressive, and if so then this is correct? Though I'm not sure about the phrasing of, "we have ever," seen; something makes me think it would make more sense with "we'd," although I couldn't place why the contraction fits better

Comment: [this is/was the best meal I have ever had/had had](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165517/this-is-was-the-best-meal-i-have-ever-had-had-had). This is a related question, but I am reluctant to close it as duplicate.

Comment: The past perfect is used for an event that is anterior to another past event. The only past event in your sentence is your attendance at the show, so the present perfect "has" is fine. And of course your opinion of shows is on-going, so the "current relevance" of the present perfect seems appropriate here.

Comment: @BillJ Always my pleasure. Your answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to add a bit to @BillJ 's comment, The present perfect suggests you are *continuing* to compare the dull one to shows seen more recently. The past perfect indicates that at some point, you ceased making comparisons to others you have seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no reason to use "had" instead of "have," at least if this is the complete context.

The tenses are perfectly fine:

- *The show **was***: Naturally, the show has finished, and was in the past.
  You can say "The show began (PAST) at 9:00," "The show starred (PAST) my uncle Bernard."
- However, the status of the list of shows you have seen continues into the present (*I have*). For example, you say "I have (PRESENT) seen *Hamilton* twice," even though both viewings occurred in the past.

Try flipping it around, and reading this sentence by itself:

> I have/*had seen six shows on Broadway, and this was one of the dullest.

On its own, *had* is incorrect here, unless you're saying it is no longer one of the dullest (because you've since seen a duller one).

Saying *had* implies the event in question (seeing) occurred before a referenced time before than the present, using regular past tense implies before the present.

For example, in the sentence I presented above, to say "had," the six shows would have to have occurred before you've seen your seventh show (an implicit second time reference).

As presented here, there is no second time reference, so without further context, it's odd, if not strictly ungrammatical, to use "had."

---

Of course, there are many ways to make it grammatical to say "had seen." But all these require expansion of the context beyond what was presented.

If you said "had," it would make it sound as if you've seen another, duller show. You could use it in a dialogue like this:

> What did you think of *Cats*?
>
> Well, until I saw *Dogs*, it was one of the dullest show I *had* ever seen.

See here that this adds a second time reference (when you saw *Dogs*), or you can do it as below:

> At that point in my life,  I had seen six shows on Broadway...

Comment: At that point in my life I had seen six shows on Broadway...  (not obviously incorrect)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *had* in this context, which is the reporting of a past event. It means that the particular show surpassed in dullness all shows previous to the particular show. The present perfect *have ever seen* includes all subsequent shows in the comparison.

Comment: @deadrat In isolation (as was presented), saying "had ever seen" is odd to me. Imagine a review of a Broadway show. No writer would end with just "*The show was one of the dullest [I] had ever seen," unless they went on to describe more recent, duller shows. But that sort information isn't in the question, so using "had" in this context remains ungrammatical to me. Maybe it's a dialectical thing, but you're welcome to add another answer.

Comment: @Jim Yes, there are ways to say "I had seen," but that's adding more information than was given in the question, but I've addressed that in my edit.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I don't know what to do with evidence from personal revelation. If it's odd or ungrammatical to you, that's what it is. But it's easy to check the claim that "[n]o writer would end" with the past perfect. They do, as the Ngram viewer reports on *worst we had ever seen*.  (Sorry, no *dullest*). As I said above, this is an unremarkable way to indicate a past interval up to and including a past reported event.

Comment: Your edit still includes “Try flipping it around... *I had seen*... Obviously *had* is incorrect here”. This just isn’t true.  It is perfectly fine here.  Also the argument with “unless you’re saying it is no longer the dullest...” is incorrect. ***had*** relates to number of shows seen, not dullest shows seen.  ***had*** implies that the speaker has now seen more than those six shows.

Comment: @deadrat It's not a personal revelation, it's a judgment from a native speaker. My point here, is yes, you can come up with scenarios that you can say "had," but all by itself, "had" is not the better choice.

Comment: @Jim If someone asks "What did you think of the show?" it would be odd to respond with "I had seen six shows, and this was one of the dullest." You can imagine someone asking "What did you think of *Cats* when you saw it as a young kid?" and respond with "Well, I had only seen six shows, but it was still one of the dullest," but that's just adding more information than was given in the question. I chose to go with the simplest interpretation of the information at hand.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - Aren’t you adding context by assuming this is spoken in response to the question, “What did you think of the show?”  I certainly did not think of it this way.  But if you’re going to think of it that way then you must also say ***when*** it was asked: At the door leaving the theater or ten years later (perhaps when they’re making a new acquaintance and realize they both were at the same show)   ***have*** would certainly be more expected at the door, and ***had*** more likely at a much later time.

Comment: @Jim I'm attempting to demonstrate the most minimal context for the sentence at hand. I didn't use a framing question in my actual answer to this question, I'm trying to show that *without adding any information* to the context, "had" is not correct. I tried to elaborate on that in my actual answer.

Comment: In general one should approach the problem of missing context by assuming a context for which the grammatically correct statement works rather than assuming a context that requires the statement to be modified.  Of course if the statement is not grammatical then you have the additional problem of trying to figure out what they wanted to say at the same time.

Comment: @Jim Yes, that's what I'm doing. The OP asked "Why didn't they say 'had'?" not "When should I say 'had,' instead of 'has'?" The answer to that question is "There is no secondary time other than the present to require the use of had_aux."

Comment: Bottom line, the statement is grammatical, therefore, absent any additional context, it is correct.

Comment: @Jim I'm glad we agree.

Comment: I’d expect an answer along the lines of: that sentence could use “have” or “had” both are correct but mean different things and imply different contexts. Here’s how they each work...   Not ***had*** is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but the meaning is different. Consider these two sentences:

> 1. It was the best meal I've ever eaten.
> 2. It was the best meal I'd ever eaten.

The meal in sentence 1 is better than any other meal I've eaten, *before or since*. The meal in sentence 2 was the best meal I had eaten up to that time; but I may have eaten better meals since.

If you say

> The show was one of the dullest we **had** ever seen,

you are specifically referring to your judgment *at the time you saw the show*.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the reason.
For adjective clauses, the tense is not required to be consistent with the main clause.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question and reads more like a comment. Please include your research and references that can support your answer.

Comment: @StoneyB Oops, you're correct.